# Error with sample code from Django docs

Tags: python, django

I copied the full example code from: [customizing admin user][1] (part of the django documentation), but when I run it the django will not  came out error,but when i add a user ,the django will the came out following error .
I have not changed any code for the example,and setting follow up the document.
follow up link is example:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

**Error:**

```
IntegrityError at /admin/app01/myuser/add/
NOT NULL constraint failed: app01_myuser.last_login
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/app01/myuser/add/
Django Version: 1.8.5
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
NOT NULL constraint failed: app01_myuser.last_login
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line       318
```

Comment: Can you please describe what's your goal. ? Whet else you changed on that code ?

Comment: Yes more info is needed to resolve this. Ensure your database is up to date (do your migrations) as from 1.7 -> 1.8 the constraints on the last_login field have changed, though this may not affect your app, I don't know! And ensure you are importing user from django.contrib.auth.models.

Comment: I have try to used new project use same code from django document,the django (1.8) running normal ,but when save the user at admin ,the error will come out,

Answer (score 0):

There is clearly a discrepancy between the custom user model you are using from the Django sample code and the definition of the table it represents in database.  The error is from the database saying the `last_login` column of the `app01_myuser` table has a `NOT NULL` constraint on it and you are trying to create a user with that field NULL.

Your `MyUser` model contains the `last_login` field inherited from `AbstractBaseUser`.  Here is the definition of `last_login` from the `AbstractBaseUser` class:

```
last_login = models.DateTimeField(_('last login'), blank=True, null=True)
```

Based on that definition of `last_login`, the `NOT NULL` constraint should not exist in your database.

Make sure your database is up to date by running migrations.  Watch for any errors that occur when running the migrations.

You can also check the `app01` migrations code to try to see when and why `app01_myuser` was created with the `NOT NULL` constraint in the first place.